# Как сделать предзагрузку изображения на JS?

Tags: javascript

Делаю предзагрузку изображений следующим образом:

```
new Image().src = "img/image1.png";
```

Но картинка не предзагружается.

Как правильно делать предзагрузку?

Или возможно я неправильно указываю путь до картинки?

Структура файлов такая (папки и файлы):

- css

  - styles.css
- img

  - image1.png
  - image2.png
- js

  - scripts.js (в этом файле прописан код предзагрузки)

Comment: Для отложенной загрузки есть amp-img

Comment: открой девтулз (F12) - Network 
и посмотри на путь загрузки картинки

"/img/image1.png";  от корня сайта